# Is there a word in English that express that something though less would suffice the need by the grace of God

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Is there a word in English to substitute *barka* in the Arabic language to mean that though something is less but can be sufficient by the grace of Allah or God.

For example: you have made a meal for four people but suddenly two more people join you. So even though in all likely consequence the food should fall short, by the grace of God it was sufficient for all six people. The word for this in Arabic is *barka.*

Comment: A real example would really help this question.

Comment: For example you have made meal for four people but suddenly two more people join you. So even though in all likely consequence the food should fall short, but by the grace of God it was sufficient for all six people, the word for this in Arabic is barka.

Comment: *Serendipity* is not far off but has nothing to do with religion - the Lexico definition is *the occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way*.

Comment: I can only think of saying that the food _miraculously_ turned out to be sufficient.

Comment: You are falling into the trap of thinking that concepts in one culture exist — or are common enough to have names — in another. In an English-speaking country like Britain, a majority of people either do not believe in the existence of a god, or do not perform any religious observances. Devout members of mainstream Christian churches may use a few set phrases invoking God, but there are few words of the type you refer to. One might say that “it was a *blessing*” that there was sufficient (or even “heaven’s blessing”) but that is just an adjective or an adjectival phrase.

Comment: The word that comes to mind is providence, often used as “divine providence”.

Comment: What’s wrong with “by the grace of God”?